# Sparkstreaming_Twitter Data

Tags: spark-streaming

I am very new to spark streaming ,i want to stream the twitter data using spark streaming, meanwhile am getting errors like

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StatusListener;)V

**used libraries**

1. spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.5.1.jar
2. twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar
3. twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar

Note:: even if am using twitter4j-*-3.03 libraies am getting error like

> lang is not a member of twitter4j.status

```
package com.mobicloud.bhavani.sparkstreaming        
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf     
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext        
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds        
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder    
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization    
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils

object TwitterData {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {    

    if (args.length < 4) {    
      System.err.println("Usage: TwitterData <ConsumerKey><ConsumerSecret><accessToken><accessTokenSecret>" +    
        "[<filters>]")
      System.exit(1)   
    }


    val appName = "TwitterData"    
    val conf = new SparkConf()    
    conf.setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[*]")    


    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))    
    val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)    
    val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)    
    val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder    
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)    
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)    
      .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)    
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)    
    val auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build)    
    val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(auth))    
   val englishTweets = tweets.filter(_.getLang() == "en")    
    englishTweets .print()    
    ssc.start()    
    ssc.awaitTermination()    

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this? locally or in a cluster? How is your build.sbt defined?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StatusListener;)

is caused by dependency mismatch b/w sparstreaming and twitter4j libraries.
Spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.5.1.jar is compatible to twitter4j **3.03** library.
but you are using twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar , twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar jars.

[check here for the dependent jars.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10/1.5.1)

If you use twitter4j-*-3.03 libraies you will get an error in this particular line `tweets.filter(_.getLang() == "en")`   because twitter4j-*-3.03 Status Interface does not have a getLang() method.This method is available only in twiiter4j-3.0.6 and later releases.

**How to Fix:**

1)Comment the filter , directly print the tweets.
or

2)Use a later version of spark streaming which is dependent on twitter4j version > 3.06  such as [spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10/1.6.1) which is dependent on twitter4j 4.0.4 version.